# What esle can we say about a sharp shooter's aiming power?

Tags: sentence-structure

Is it possible to tell about a sharp shooter:

> - His / her aiming is great / perfect / etc.

Does the sentence above make sense to you? Is it natural?

Answer (score 2):

It's more idiomatic to say his/her *aim*, rather than "aiming", but other than that, it looks fine.

*Aim* in this context is a noun and means "the ability to hit a target": [see definition 8 here.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/aim)

*Aiming*, as a gerund, means something more like "one specific action of aiming".  So you would say "While she was *aiming* her rifle..." but her general ability to aim a weapon is *her aim*.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence is not grammatically correct (see @stangdon's answer) and is not at all idiomatic. There are several expressions that people use when talking about shooting:

> He is a [dead shot](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dead-shot)
>   He is a [sharpshooter](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sharpshooter)
>   His aim [with a rifle] is very [accurate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/accurate)
>   He aims with [pinpoint accuracy](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pinpoint-accuracy)

Answer (score 1):

The idea that someone is good enough at shooting to hit the bull's eye most of the time may be expressed by '*he's a good shot/aim*' or '*he has a good shot/aim*'. This was once discussed on ELU (for details see [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20700/constructions-like-a-good-shot)).  The person skilled in shooting is *a sharpshooter* or *a marksman*.